# Python - find an expression in a list filled with strings

Tags: python

I would like to find a specific entry in a list filled with strings. For example, I would like to find all the strings that contain the number ".0130." (like the 3rd line below)

The file looks like this:

```
https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2018/001/MYD021KM.A2018001.0140.006.2018002030901.hdf
https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2018/001/MYD021KM.A2018001.0135.006.2018002030858.hdf
https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2018/001/MYD021KM.A2018001.0130.006.2018002030850.hdf
https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/archive/allData/6/MYD021KM/2018/001/MYD021KM.A2018001.0125.006.2018002030903.hdf
```

I read the file like this:

```
data_links = []
f=open(workdir1+"/download.txt", "r")
for i in f:
    data_links.append(i.rstrip())
f.close()
```

How could I look for all the entries containing the section ".0130."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = [line for line in file if ".0130" in line]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use regex as well

```
import re
[i for i in your_list if(re.search('\.0130\.',i) is not None)]
```